# how to figure out the current used bluetooth firmware

Tags: bluetooth, ubuntu-touch, firmware

i am currently on an Ubuntu Touch device and try to figure out if a firmware update of bluetooth worked out. How do I get to know the right command to figure out the bluetooth firmware. dmesg shows too much and lspci doesn't exist as a command. Is there a way to easily display just a short line that states my bluetooth firmware? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hciconfig -a |  grep HCI
```

will show a HCI version. Example result

```
HCI Version: 5.2 (0xb)  Revision: 0x27a4
```

= BT 5.2

```
 hciconfig -a
```

for more info. There is also [hcitool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/hcitool.1.html).

```
hcitool inq
```

will get you mac address.

```
hcitool info {mac}
```

will show features for that mac address.The question in comment:

```
hcitool con
```

shows the active baseband connection.

Comment: Thank you Rinzwind! I consider the question as solved but I would like to know if you can get any other information about Bluetooth somehow like the baseband version through the terminal. So if anybody knows, just write it in the thread thanks!

Comment: drop the `| grep HCI` and you get  a lot more info.

Comment: Thanks again! That was helpful